# Trouble Bootloading Custom PCB with nRF52840 - Serial Port Not Detected

Tags: serial-port, bootloader, nrf52840

I'm encountering a challenge with my custom PCB, which incorporates an nRF52840 IC using the schematic of the Seed Xiao development board as a reference. While I can successfully bootload the Seed Xiao board and see the corresponding serial port on my computer, I'm unable to achieve the same result with my custom PCB. The serial port doesn't appear after the bootloading process.

Details:

Background: I initially developed my project on the Seed Xiao platform and now need to integrate the Seed Xiao's circuitry into my final custom PCB design.

Issue: The main problem lies in bootloading the nRF52840 IC on my custom PCB. Unlike the Seed Xiao, the serial port doesn't show up on my computer during the bootloading process.

What I've Tried:

Checked the hardware connections to ensure they match the Seed Xiao's configuration.
Attempted to bootload using different USB ports and cables.
Ensured that there are no conflicts with other software using the COM port. Able to upload hex file to my custom pcb using swdio and swclk pins.

Observations:

When using the Seed Xiao, I can successfully bootload the nRF52840 IC, and the serial port appears on my computer, indicating proper communication.
Request for Help:

I'm seeking guidance on troubleshooting this issue with my custom PCB. Are there any specific considerations or differences I should be aware of when adapting the Seed Xiao circuitry to a custom PCB with an nRF52840 IC?
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or has insights into potential solutions?
I would greatly appreciate any advice, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps to help resolve this issue and successfully bootload the nRF52840 IC on my custom PCB. Thank you for your assistance.